Open a TCP/IP connection via socket with a label printer
I want to open a TCP/IP connection with a Zebra printer to send ZPL commands to print. I can do this with NodeJS but no with web sockets.
NodeJS
var s = require('net').Socket();
s.connect(9100, '192.168.0.99');
s.write(zpl_commands);

but can't send commands on websocket, I don't want to make a intermediary server with NodeJS that prints. Any idea if I can achieve this? I already try making a chrome plugin and didn't work.
My websocket code
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.99:9100');

socket.send(message);

I need to work with Chrome, because I connect a weight machine with a serial port. It's a possible solution to connect the printer into the computer via cable (but I would like via wifi, so I can print from several terminals)
Note: if put in my browser ws://... I can connect to the printer 'printServer'
Note2: The printer is a Zebra ZD420

Your printer does not support WebSockets. Why do you expect it to work like this? A network socket, no matter if tcp or udp is not automatically a WebSocket. WebSocket works in a higher layer than tcp sockets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model tcp/udp layer 4, http/ws = layer 7

@Marc I read on a Zebra document that some printers does support WebSocket, and mine have a "print Server" but I think it only works for configurations. But is there any way that a chrome web app can connect in a lower layer? My current solution is to make a NodeJS intermediate app, that the web app send the print signal to the server, then the server to the printer client

You could write a "proxy" that provides a WebSocket server/endpoint and forward that to your printer. (https://github.com/novnc/websockify, https://github.com/erebe/wstunnel, https://github.com/mhzed/wstunnel). Where did you read that some printer support WebSockets? Theoretical its possible, but i dont see/get why a printer manufacturer would implement/do that. WebSockets are usually not a way to tell a printer what to do. There are other standards/implementations that suits that requirement

A quick search with the keywords "Zebra ZD420 websocket": When connected to a wired or wireless network, the printer attempts to connect to Zebra's Asset Visibility Service through the cloud-based Zebra Printer Connector using an encrypted, certificate-authenticated web socket connection. That does not mean you can tell the printer via WebSocket what to print. If you are fine with my proxy approach, i would provide a possible solution.

@Marc, Clearly I miss understand because the web socket. About the proxy I was thinking on writing a small local server that re-direct the ZPL commands to the printer, sure the user needs to install an extra program that will run on the background and open a local port 24/7 but it's an industrial application I'm sure it doesn't matter. So now via sockets I will send the data from the web to the local server. It's similar to the solution you think?

Sorry, i dont know what you mean with "sockets" or what you miss understand. Please use clear wording like "Network Sockets" which refer to TCP/UDP sockets, or "WebSockets" which refer to higher protocols like HTTP/WebSocket that use TCP as Transport.

My bad,  I mean that I open a small local server in NodeJS app that opens a web socket, then the web app send the ZPL to the local server. Then the NodeJS App opens a Network Socket with the printer and send all the commands.

Exactly. Thats how you should do it. I posted a answer, that implements that logic.

As pointed out in my comment, the printer does not have a support for a WebSocket endpoint where you can send commands to it.
Rather you have to write/use a proxy that creates a WebSocket/HTTP endpoint, which forwards the data send to it, to the underlaying TCP Socket connected to the printer.
const { WebSocketServer, createWebSocketStream } = require("ws");
const { Socket } = require("net");



const { 
    WEBSOCKET_HOST, 
    WEBSOCKET_PORT, 
    PRINTER_HOST, 
    PRINTER_PORT 
} = Object.assign({
    WEBSOCKET_HOST: "127.0.0.1",
    WEBSOCKET_PORT: "8320",
    PRINTER_HOST: "127.0.0.1",
    PRINTER_PORT: "1900"
}, process.env);


const server = new WebSocketServer({
    port: Number(WEBSOCKET_PORT),
    host: WEBSOCKET_HOST
});


server.once("listening", () => {
    console.log(`WebSocket server listening on ws://${WEBSOCKET_HOST}:${WEBSOCKET_PORT} for connections`);
});


server.on("connection", (ws) => {

    let socket = new Socket();
    let stream = createWebSocketStream(ws);

    socket.once("connect", () => {
        console.log("Connected to printer");
    });

    // pipe data from websocket to tcp socket
    // pipe data from tcp socket to websocket
    stream.pipe(socket);
    socket.pipe(stream);

    // connecto to printer via tcp socket
    socket.connect(Number(PRINTER_PORT), PRINTER_HOST);

});

The code above is very simple and straight forwarded.
It creates a HTTP/WebSocket server/endpoint, where clients (like Browser, wscat, etc.) can connect to, which then creates a TCP Socket to the printer.
You can test this with netcat & wscat.
First, create a dummy tcp server/printer via: nc -l -p 1900.
This tells netcat to create a tcp socket for incoming requests on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) on port 1900.
The start the WebSocket proxy above (after installing the websocket module via npm install ws): node tcp-ws-proxy.js.
At last, connect via the WebSocket CLI client wscat --connect ws://127.0.0.1:8320 and enter some data, e.g. "Hello Netcat".
What ever you enter, should be printed on the netcat console/terminal/output.
This allows you to connect via a WebSocket client, like a Browser, to your printer.
Modules/CLI tools used:

wscat
ws
netcat

Written & tested on Ubuntu 23.10, Node 20.11.0
EDIT:
Because Bergi mentioned it in the comments, i should have mentioned that you have to properly secure the WebSocket endpoint. Otherwise everyone could send print commands to the printer.

"The code is very simple and straight forward" - and insecure. If you expose such privileged functionality via websockets, you must check the origin header! Otherwise any arbitrary web page the user opens can start printing whatever it wants.

Sure, no doubt about that. The code is a reference implementation and not a "copy & paste" solution. Since when is SO a "perfect copy this and print money with it" solution? A authentication mechanism would blow this answer/question, sine no one know how OP wants to use it. If you know a better solution, feel free to create a answer. BTW: origin header can be manipulated, or is compeletly bypassed if used via CLI tools like wscat, so your "security mechanism" is also terrible implement and snake oil. My code is a example how a possible do it.

An answer that doesn't even mention authentication here is a bad answer. The origin verification would be trivial to implement (just pass a verifyClient callback). And no, the origin header cannot be manipulated by browser clients, which are the issue here as they execute arbitrary untrusted code. Other clients in the network could just open a TCP connection directly to the printer anyway.

If you have a WebSocket endpoint public, who cares about Browsers? And no, the origin header cannot be manipulated by browser clients (which are the issue here). Right, but a attacker could still send whatever he want in such header, so relaying on it as security reason is just stupid...

OP wrote "I was thinking on writing a small local server that re-direct the ZPL commands to the printer, sure the user needs to install an extra program that will run on the background and open a local port 24/7 but it's an industrial application", so I assumed that this would not be a public (on the internet) endpoint but rather an application installed on the same computer as the browser running the web application (or at least in the same intranet as the printer). For a public endpoint, you're totally right, the threat scenario is different there and auth cannot rely on origin alone

And? What you think and what OP does, are completely different. If this run on a Computer where only the local user/browser has access to it, why so mad about authentication? Here on SO are much terrible security risk, and you are mad about a printer? I added a note about security in my answer. Relax bro.

"If this run on a Computer where only the local user/browser has access to it, why so mad about authentication?" - exactly because this is insecure, with a risk that is easily overlooked: the local browser may open arbitrary websites, not only yours, and they all can access the websocket endpoint equally - apart from the origin header.

You have a point. Can you explain that more/detailed how a attack would look like? I think i misunderstood you in the first place. How can a example.com website access the websocket endpoint on 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.4.210. Just by calling new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8320")? That would be indeed a security risk. But shouldn't the attacker know that such a service is listening?

Yes, creating new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8320") is enough. There is no same-origin policy or similar that would prevent accessing the socket. But yeah, the attacker will probably need to know about the service beforehand, I doubt there would be a port-scanning and protocol-guessing generic malware in the wild. But if you are targeted, or even just if this printing application becomes common enough to have a hacker take a look, they might write a dedicated virus… just for fun!

Thanks! And actually I will send a unique print job code that the server should check on my api that the unique print job ID exists and return the ZPL commands.
